# Why do these logical expressions generate these answers in matlab?

Tags: matlab, math

```
>> 1 < 5 > 2
ans =
  logical
   0
>> 1 < 5 > 2 < 1
ans =
  logical
   1
```

Why do these logical expressions generate these answers in matlab? Can someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB does not calculate such expressions as a logical combination of the individual inequalities.

`a<b<c` is not the same as `a<b AND b<c`

It calculates them in order of precedence and left to right.

`a<b<c` is thus calculated as if it were `d = a<b` (d being logical 0 or 1) then `d<c`

So your expressions expand to
`1<5 = logical 1 
 1>2 = logical 0 
 0<1 = logical 1`